# Compare the value that is entered on textbox with a value that is already inputed and exists in a cell with offset 2. Then remove duplicates on cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want the program to check if the textbox value that was inputted matches a value that was already inputted and saved on a cell before / or exists already and then make a pop up message that does not allow the second input and / or removes the duplicates so that later I can filter only one model name with each own quantities.
Ex. Model name SM150 then user inputs SM150. In the current situation it will save it again in the cells next to the active one and then I can not extract the total items used.[image]
[image: Diff model numbers]
[image]

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter value"
    Else
    
'        If ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Find(What:=TextBox3.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
'            MsgBox "Already Exists! Please modify it on sheet"
'        End If
'        If InStr(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, TextBox3.Value) > 0 Then
'        MsgBox "The string contains the value."
'    Else
'        MsgBox "The string doesn't contain the value."
'    End If
        
        
        Dim search2 As String
        search2 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Value
'        If ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Find(What:=TextBox3.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) = True Then
'            MsgBox "True Shit"
'        Else
'            MsgBox "False"
'            End If
'
        Debug.Print StrComp(search2, TextBox3.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0
'        If StrComp(search2, TextBox3.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'           MsgBox StrComp(search2, TextBox3.Value, vbTextCompare)
'           Else
'           MsgBox "nothing"
'          End If
           
'        MsgBox LTrim$(Mid$(search2, InStr(1, search2, CHAR(10)) + 1))
'        If LTrim$(Mid$(search2, InStr(1, search2, CHAR(10)) + 1)) = search2 Then
'           MsgBox LTrim$(Mid$(search2, InStr(1, search2, CHAR(10)) + 1))
'        Else
'            MsgBox "nothing of calue"
'        End If
        
'        If tosearch Is Nothing Then
'            MsgBox "Nothing"
'        Else
'            MsgBox tosearch
'        End If
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried the examples that are commented above but i was always getting errors with sub or object or variable not set etc.

Answer (score 1):

- The Change event is triggered whenever a user inputs or deletes a character in TextBox3. There is no need to validate it during user input.
- Use `Exit` event to validate the content of TextBox3 when it lose focus.
- There isn't the code of commandbutton `Done` in your post. I'm not sure what's the meaning of `removes the duplicates`.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter value"
    Else
        If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, TextBox3.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "The string contains the value."
            ' Clear user's input
            TextBox3.Value = ""
        Else
            MsgBox "The string doesn't contain the value."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer mister. 
The remove duplicates is meant for: if the user inputs the same model twice, I do not want it registered as ID (ex. sm150) but rather i only want to keep the stock and price and increase the previous stock and price variables by the new amount.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the values are separated by vbNewLine and this comparisson you wrote it works but because a model number can also be sm150b sm150c etc gets detected as duplicate even though is not.
I tried a similar solution found in another topic but I can not make it work, error function undefined 
LTrim$(Mid$(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, InStr(1, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, CHAR(10)) + 1))

Comment: `I do not want it registered as ID (ex. sm150) but rather i only want to keep the stock and price and increase the previous stock and price variables by the new amount. ` - I guess it is the function of cmd button `Done` .

Comment: If sm150, sm150b, sm150c considered as duplicated model, do you want to only keep `sm150` on col `Model`? If the first input is `sm150b` (Model cell is blankon worksheet ), how do the code know which part of input (sm150, m150b...) is the model string?   `the values are separated by vbNewLine` do you mean multiple models in a cell? I would suggest you edit your post to share sample and the processing logic.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Dear Taller. Thank you for your comment. I will edit my post with more pictures. 
In general i have 5 models sm150a to sm150e. And I want to do an exact match in order to prevent myself or colleague of entering the same model twice in one order. (So yes multiple models in a cell, not only sm150 etc but also other examples like cronos5001 etc